# Memory Blow Up when using Dask compute or persist with Dask Delayed

Tags: dask

I am trying to process the data of several subjects all in one dataframe. There are >30 subjects and 14 computations per subject it is a large data set but any more than 5 blows up the memory on the scheduler node with out running any workers on the same node as the scheduler it has 128gb of memory? Any ideas how I can get around this or if im doing something wrong? code bellow.

```
def channel_select(chn,sub):

    subject = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df['sub'] == sub])
    subject['s0'] = subject[chn]
    val = []
    for x in range(13):
        for i in range(len(subject)):
            val.append(subject['s0'].values[i-x])
        name = 's' + str(x+1)
        subject[name] = val
        val = []
    return subject

subs = df['sub'].unique()
subs = np.delete(subs, [34,33])

for s in subs:
    for c in chn:
        chn_del.append(delayed(channel_select)(c,subs[s]))

results = e.persist(pred)
```

I have the code shown to run all the subjects but anymore than 5 at a time and I run out of memory

Comment: What are the dimensions of `df` here, and where does `pred` come from? I note that `df` must be a global included in the function closure, and that your code is very loopy, so that it can probably be rewritten with better pandas methods.

Comment: You could try `e.scatter(df)` and pass `df` in the function signature to avoid copying it in directly in the graph X number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling the computer to keep almost 1,000 GB of memory.

But you knew that already (:

Answer (score 0):

As Mary stated above, every call to channel_select created and stores the dataframe on the schedulers memory, with 30 subjects calling 14 time each and a 2gb dataframe...yeah you can do the math of how much memory that was trying grab.